# Streaming video

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a media player implemented windows store application. In this application, users will be able to watch stream through the mediaplayer. I will provide the stream link in c# code like an url. When users click play, they will watch the stream. How can i do that? Mediaplayer code is here:

```
int flag = 0;
        private Size _previousVideoContainerSize = new Size();

        private void FullscreenToggle()
        {
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _previousVideoContainerSize.Width = videoContainer.ActualWidth;
                _previousVideoContainerSize.Height = videoContainer.ActualHeight;
                videoContainer.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
                videoContainer.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                exit.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                inn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                videoContainer.Width = _previousVideoContainerSize.Width;
                videoContainer.Height = _previousVideoContainerSize.Height;
                exit.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                inn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void btnFullScreenToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FullscreenToggle();
        }

        private void VideoContainer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (flag == 1 && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape)
            {
                FullscreenToggle();
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate != 1)
            {
                videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
            }

            videoMediaElement.Play();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Stop();
        }

        private void btnVolumeDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
            {
                videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
            }

            if (videoMediaElement.Volume < 1)
            {
                videoMediaElement.Volume += .1;

            }
            vol.Value -= 5;
        }
        private void btnMute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            videoMediaElement.IsMuted = !videoMediaElement.IsMuted;
        }
        private void btnVolumeUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
            {
                videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
            }

            if (videoMediaElement.Volume > 0)
            {
                videoMediaElement.Volume -= .1;
            }
            vol.Value += 5;
        }
```

My regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of options:

Option 1: Here is a good tutorial that explains how to implement video streaming using the Smooth Streaming Client SDK: [Building Windows Store Apps with Smooth Streaming Client SDK](http://mingfeiy.com/building-windows-store-apps-smooth-streaming-client-sdk-beta-2/)

Option 2: Another approach is to use the [Player Framework for Windows 8 Metro Style Applications](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/media-platform-player-framework)
To summarize, this is an open source, robust video player framework for Windows 8, HTML5, Silverlight, Windows Phone and other application platforms.

Option 3: [A Simple Windows 8 Smooth Streaming Media Player with a Slider Bar Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-simple-Windows-8-Smooth-ee98f63a)

To summarize: This sample shows how to use Smooth Streaming Client SDK for Windows 8 to create a Windows Store application to playback Smooth Streaming content. In the sample, the MediaElement control is used to show the media content, and a slider bar control is used to control the progress.
That`s is from me, just pick one of the options and you are ready to go.